# arch linux CCS install stuck at com.ti.debug

Tags: ide, installation, archlinux

when I start to install CCS it works normall untill it went to install com.ti.debug.linux... and it stucks at this line.
I have opened task manager to watch the activity and it just runs some java then stuck.

```html
03/22/2017 00:04:35(GMT) - my - creating constructor MSP-EXP430G2 MSP-EXP430FR5739 MSP-EXP430FR4133 MSP-EXP430F5438 EZ430-F2013 EZ430-CHRONOS image1 image2 image3 image4 image5 image6
03/22/2017 00:04:35(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - LD_LIBRARY_PATH == :/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/tcl/lib
03/22/2017 00:04:35(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - tempLD == {}
03/22/2017 00:04:35(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - cmd = /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/check_depends.sh --ldpath 
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - ran /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/check_depends.sh --ldpath :Installed versions of glibc and glibcxx: 2.25, N/A
Required versions of glibc and glibcxx:  2.15, GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_INSTALLED: 2.25
GLIBC_REQUIRED: 2.15
Checking availability of libraries in ext-depends.txt ...
Done.
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: Installed versions of glibc and glibcxx: 2.25, N/A
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: Required versions of glibc and glibcxx:  2.15, GLIBCXX_3.4.19
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: GLIBC_INSTALLED: 2.25
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - GLIBC_INSTALLED: 2.25
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: GLIBC_REQUIRED: 2.15
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - GLIBC_REQUIRED: 2.15
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: Checking availability of libraries in ext-depends.txt ...
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Line: Done.
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - Installed version 2.25 is greater than or equal to 2.15
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxGlibCheck - 
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - LD_LIBRARY_PATH == :/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/tcl/lib
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - tempLD == {}
03/22/2017 00:04:36(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - cmd = /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/ldcheck
03/22/2017 00:04:37(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - ran /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/ldcheck:
03/22/2017 00:04:37(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - cmd = /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/check_depends.sh --ldpath 
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - ran /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/dependency-checker/check_depends.sh --ldpath :Installed versions of glibc and glibcxx: 2.25, N/A
Required versions of glibc and glibcxx:  2.15, GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_INSTALLED: 2.25
GLIBC_REQUIRED: 2.15
Checking availability of libraries in ext-depends.txt ...
Done.
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: Installed versions of glibc and glibcxx: 2.25, N/A
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: Required versions of glibc and glibcxx:  2.15, GLIBCXX_3.4.19
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: GLIBC_INSTALLED: 2.25
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: GLIBC_REQUIRED: 2.15
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: Checking availability of libraries in ext-depends.txt ...
03/22/2017 00:04:38(GMT) - Validation::linuxLibChecks - Line: Done.
03/22/2017 00:04:45(GMT) - ::installDirPane0 - InstallDir selected: /home/islam/ti
03/22/2017 00:04:45(GMT) - my - numRootsSelected 0
03/22/2017 00:04:45(GMT) - my - numRootsSelected 0
03/22/2017 00:04:45(GMT) - my - numRootsSelected 0
03/22/2017 00:04:48(GMT) - my - numRootsSelected 1
03/22/2017 00:04:49(GMT) - my - numRootsSelected 2
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - 

Install Information:


03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Install Version: 7.1.0.00016
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Install Source : /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Install Temp : /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Install Type : Offline
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - OS    : Linux
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - OS Name  : Unknown Linux
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - OS Version  : 4.10.3-1-ARCH
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - OS Platform : unix
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile -             : 64-bit
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - ::programArgs0 - OSD: UnknownLinux-64-bit
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile -             : UnknownLinux-64-bit
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - User ID  : islam
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Timezone  : EET
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IPAddress  : 
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Update/Rerun : 0
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - Command line : installersrc /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64 installertmp /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0 buildid 7.1.0.00016 installer /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/ccs_setup_linux64_7.1.0.00016.bin bitness 64-bit os linux-x64 osname {Unknown Linux} spversion NONE timestamp 20170322020429 AVon false

03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - CCS_WARNING: {Failed to locate system libraries required for CCS operation:

}
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - 
Product families selected: 
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - PF_MSP430
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - PF_TM4C
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - 
Components to be installed: 
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - EMU_TI
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_MSP430
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - MSP430_BUILD_DEBUG
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - MSP430_GCC_SUPPORT
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - EMU_MSP430
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TIVA_STELLARIS_DRIVERS
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - JRE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - P2APP
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - ECLIPSE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - ECLIPSECORE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - P2TOOLS
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - GMF
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_MAIN
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_WORKFLOW
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DVT_COMMON
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DVT_UIA
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DVT_VIA_CCS
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TIREX
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - XULRUNNER
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - INSTALLER
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_CHROME
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_TOOLS_COMMON
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_GC
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TARGET_CONTENT_CORE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TARGET_CONTENT_CORE_LEGACY
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - NODEJS
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - PINMUX
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DS
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DS_FLASH
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - CLOUDAGENT
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - MSP430_CGT_HELP
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - CGT_DEFAULTLIBS_MSP430
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DMED
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DVT_ENERGYTRACE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - IDE_ARM
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - DVT_TRACE
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TIVA_TM4C
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - TIVA_TM4E
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - ARM_CGT_HELP
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - CGT_DEFAULTLIBS_TMS470
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - writeDebugFile - GCC_ARM_COMPILER
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - Finish Status Num of families selected: 2 ; num families available: 20
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - ::programArgs128 - OSD: UnknownLinux-64-bit
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for ARM_CGT_HELP: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for C2000_CGT_HELP: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for C6000_CGT_HELP: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - Did not find matching component in InstallIni CCS_DOC. Using Defaults.
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - Did not find matching component in InstallIni CCS_LAUNCHER. Using Defaults.
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - Did not find matching component in InstallIni CCS_UTILS. Using Defaults.
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for DVT_COMMON: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for DVT_ENERGYTRACE: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for DVT_TRACE: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for DVT_UIA: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for DVT_VIA_CCS: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for ECLIPSE: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for EMU_SD: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/ccs_base
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_ARM: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_C2000: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_C5500: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_C6000: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_CHROME: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_GC: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_MAIN: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_MSP430: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_TOOLS_COMMON: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for IDE_WORKFLOW: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for MSP430_BUILD_DEBUG: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for MSP430_CGT_HELP: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for MSP430_GCC_SUPPORT: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for MSP432_BUILD_DEBUG: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for P2APP: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for P2TOOLS: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - Did not find matching component in InstallIni TARGETDB_DEF_PROPS. Using Defaults.
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for TARGET_CONTENT_CORE: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/..
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - my - installdir for TARGET_CONTENT_CORE_LEGACY: /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/..
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - Util::getProperty - No /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs.properties file found
03/22/2017 00:05:11(GMT) - Util::getProperty - No /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs.properties file found
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - ProgressPane::Run - non-threaded
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - ProgressPane::Run - RunInstall /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs_config.xml 0 0 0 0 /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/install_logs/20170322020429/ccs_setup_7.1.0.00016_install.log ::progressPane0 -1
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - RunMain - CCS_INFO: Started with params pConfigFile=/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs_config.xml pProfiling=0 pUpdate=0 logfile=/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/install_logs/20170322020429/ccs_setup_7.1.0.00016_install.log progress=::progressUpdate0
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - RunMain - CCS_INFO: encoding = utf-8
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - Start installing components:
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - read config file /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs_config.xml
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - found /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/ccs_config.xml
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - Parsing Root Elements
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - Done Parsing
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - CCSDIR=/home/islam/ti/ccsv7
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - EclipseDir=/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - InstallDir=/home/islam/ti
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - TempDir=/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - platform=linux-x64
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - LocalBaseRepository=/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - baserepourl=/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - featureurl=/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - LocalRepository_Exists=1
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - componentinstaller=false
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - eclipseexe=eclipse
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readConfigFile - in install components
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - readUserProfile - userprofile = 
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - RunMain - Update = 0
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - deleted /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - copying /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo/binary/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - copied /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo/binary/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122 to /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - File /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122 already exists. Not attempting to download
03/22/2017 00:05:12(GMT) - extract - cmd = "unzip" -q -o -d "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0" "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122"
03/22/2017 00:05:14(GMT) - extract - successfully unzipped /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/jre_root.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.8.0.122
03/22/2017 00:05:14(GMT) - extract - cmd = "unzip" -q -o -d "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse" "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/downloads/jre-8u112-linux-x64.zip"
03/22/2017 00:05:21(GMT) - extract - successfully unzipped /tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/downloads/jre-8u112-linux-x64.zip
03/22/2017 00:05:21(GMT) - installEclipse - In InstallEclipse for linux-x64
03/22/2017 00:05:21(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - File /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/eclipse_core_4.5.1.custom-160121.zip already exists. Not attempting to download
03/22/2017 00:05:21(GMT) - extract - cmd = "unzip" -q -o -d "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0" "/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/eclipse_core_4.5.1.custom-160121.zip"
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - extract - successfully unzipped /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/eclipse_core_4.5.1.custom-160121.zip
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - findLauncher - launcher version = 1.3.100.v20150511-1540
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - installEclipse - CCS_INFO: eclipse does not exist
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - installEclipse - using /home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/jre/bin/java
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - installEclipse - "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/jre/bin/java" -Xmx512m -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=30000 -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=10000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000  "-Dosgi.configuration.area=/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/cfg" "-Dosgi.instance.area=/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/ws" -jar "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/eclipserepo" -installIU org.eclipse.platform.ide,org.eclipse.help.feature.group,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group,org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group,org.eclipse.rse.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group,org.eclipse.gef.feature.group,gnu.io.rxtx.feature.group,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.thirdparty.feature.group -destination "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/" -profile epp.package.cpp -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -bundlepool "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/" -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86_64 -roaming 
03/22/2017 00:05:22(GMT) - runEclipseApp - running cmd "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/jre/bin/java" -Xmx512m -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=30000 -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=10000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000  "-Dosgi.configuration.area=/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/cfg" "-Dosgi.instance.area=/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/ws" -jar "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/eclipserepo" -installIU org.eclipse.platform.ide,org.eclipse.help.feature.group,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group,org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group,org.eclipse.rse.feature.group,org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group,org.eclipse.gef.feature.group,gnu.io.rxtx.feature.group,org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.thirdparty.feature.group -destination "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/" -profile epp.package.cpp -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -bundlepool "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/" -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86_64 -roaming 
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - runEclipseApp - Installing org.eclipse.platform.ide 4.6.0.I20160607-1100.
Installing org.eclipse.help.feature.group 2.2.0.v20160606-1100.
Installing org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group 1.0.400.v20160504-1450.
Installing org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.2.200.v20160606-1311.
Installing org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 9.0.0.201606062011.
Installing org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group 9.0.0.201606062011.
Installing org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group 4.1.0.201606052351.
Installing org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group 1.5.0.v20160608-1804.
Installing org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.4.0.201606070830-r.
Installing org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group 9.0.0.201606062011.
Installing org.eclipse.rse.feature.group 3.7.1.201603211627.
Installing org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group 9.0.0.201606062011.
Installing org.eclipse.gef.feature.group 3.11.0.201606061308.
Installing gnu.io.rxtx.feature.group 2.1.8.0_201606281300.
Installing org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.thirdparty.feature.group 1.10.0.201606071959.
Operation completed in 142787 ms.
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - runEclipseApp - done.
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - installEclipse - eclipse installed successfully, looking for binary
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - installEclipse - new state: feature installed
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - downloadIfRequired - File /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/updateinstaller.zip already exists. Not attempting to download
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - extract - cmd = "unzip" -q -o -d "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse" "/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/updateinstaller.zip"
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - extract - successfully unzipped /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/updateinstaller.zip
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - installP2app - "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/eclipse" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/p2appfRepo" -installiu com.ti.ccstudio.p2appf.feature.group -nosplash 
03/22/2017 00:07:56(GMT) - runEclipseApp - running cmd "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/eclipse" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/p2appfRepo" -installiu com.ti.ccstudio.p2appf.feature.group -nosplash 
03/22/2017 00:08:28(GMT) - runEclipseApp - Installing com.ti.ccstudio.p2appf.feature.group 6.0.0.201703152000.
Operation completed in 7323 ms.
03/22/2017 00:08:28(GMT) - runEclipseApp - done.
03/22/2017 00:08:28(GMT) - removeURL - cmdline = "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/eclipse"  -data "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/workspace" -application com.ti.ccstudio.p2app -removerepo "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/p2appfRepo" -nosplash
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - removeURL - successfully ran "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/eclipse"  -data "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/workspace" -application com.ti.ccstudio.p2app -removerepo "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/baserepo/p2appfRepo" -nosplash
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - length of features = 75; 1; 0
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - processing JRE
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - JRE state: feature installed; does not need to be processed
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - length of features = 75; 2; 0
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - processing ECLIPSECORE
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - ECLIPSECORE state: feature installed; does not need to be processed
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - length of features = 75; 3; 0
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - processing ECLIPSE
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - ECLIPSE state: feature installed; does not need to be processed
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - length of features = 75; 4; 0
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - processing DS
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - state:initial
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - binary:ti_dspack_ibsetup_linux-x64_7.1.0.1971.run
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - location = /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - newloc:file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - counting = 6; 4  75
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - fullrepolist file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - fullfeaturelist com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.group
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - found_msp_repo: false
03/22/2017 00:08:48(GMT) - runEclipseApp - running cmd "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/eclipse" -data "/tmp/ccs_9126e521-a4d2-4701-753f-7c660d522ea0/workspace" -application com.ti.ccstudio.p2app -repository "file:/home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo" -installiu com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.group -nosplash 
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - runEclipseApp - Installing com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.group 7.1.0.1971.
Downloading com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux
Downloading com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux_root.gtk.linux.x86_64
Installing com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.group
Installing com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.jar
Installing com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux_root.gtk.linux.x86_64
Configuring com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.group
Configuring com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux.feature.jar
Configuring com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux_root.gtk.linux.x86_64
Preparing to commit the provisioning operation.
Committing the provisioning operation.
Operation completed in 19338 ms.
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - runEclipseApp - done.
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - Processing DS to install
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - current state = initial
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - false false initial
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - location = /home/islam/Downloads/CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64/featurerepo
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - Binary=/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/downloads/ti_dspack_ibsetup_linux-x64_7.1.0.1971.run
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - Setting state to feature registered
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - get_percentage - values 15722706 701337160 35
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - get_percentage - increase by 0.7846364650063602
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - processOtherFeatures - CCS_INFO: binary ti_dspack_ibsetup_linux-x64_7.1.0.1971.run; ext = .run
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - InstallBins - .run: ti_dspack_ibsetup_linux-x64_7.1.0.1971.run --mode unattended --ccs true  --prefix "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7" --eclipseprefix  "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse" 
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - InstallBins - cmd = "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse/downloads/ti_dspack_ibsetup_linux-x64_7.1.0.1971.run" --mode unattended --ccs true  --prefix "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7" --eclipseprefix  "/home/islam/ti/ccsv7/eclipse" 
03/22/2017 00:09:19(GMT) - InstallBins - CCS_INFO: Installing com.ti.ccstudio.debugserver.linux
```

My version is the latest CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64
What is wrong with the installer?
Are there better  alternatives?
thanks in advance

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also experienced this hanging. On my system (Archlinux) I identified glibc-2.25 to be the cause of the problem. Downgrading to glibc-2.24 solved this issue.

Tested with CCS7.1.0.00016_linux-x64.tar.gz

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Thanks I will try it now.

Comment: That worked this archive contains old repo.

https://archive.archlinux.org/repos/2017/03/10/core/os/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

Some updates on this issue : ccs 7.4. solves glibc dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading glibc can break lot of dependencies.

[Another approach](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User:Ctag/CCS) uses chroot, but it consumes > 6G

Some steps are missing in wiki, you have to enable multilib repo in `/etc/pacman.conf` (uncomment line) in order to install `lib32-glibc`

After, I couldn't have App Center and other embedded browser windows. To get it I modified Browser in `Preferences -> Code Composer Studio` to `JavaFX Web kit`.